# SoundCloud API Search for Tracks with Tags Filter

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

I'm trying to use the following code to generate a list of songs that have a given tag. However, each time I invoke the function, I get the same list of only ten tracks. I tried using the genre filter before this and ran into the same problem. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

```
SC.get('/tracks', { tags: 'hip-hop' }).then(function(tracks) {
    console.log(tracks);
});
```

Comment: Do you want more than ten songs or random songs in the "hip-hop" tags?

Comment: Ideally random songs! I'm trying to make a playlist generator.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way could be to increase the number of results and select a track from that randomly.

```
function randomTrack(genre, limiter){
  SC.get('/tracks', {genres:genre, limit:limiter})
    .then(function(tracks) {        
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (limiter-1));
        console.log(tracks[random].title);    
});
}
randomTrack('hiphop', 50);
```

And / or add more filters to the function.